# Soundcloud XML does not work with some links?

Tags: xml, api, soundcloud

I use `http://soundcloud.com/oembed?format=xml&url=AND_SOME_LINK_HERE` to get all the information to the xml file for a tune. It have worked with all links I have tried except from this one: `https://soundcloud.com/dexterbritain/the-time-to-run-finale`. Why is the XML file for this tune empty?

Regards, 
allegutta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The server returns a 403 Forbidden response on that URL so my guess is there's a licensing restriction or a restriction from the author that prevents it being available for embedding.

If you go to that page in the browser and click "Share" it doesn't offer embedding options like other items on the site do.

Comment: Sorry for late reply! Thats probably it. Thanks :)